# Windows 11 - Time synchronization failed

Tags: windows, windows-11

No sure why Windows time synchronization doesn't work at all for me.

I have installed clean Windows 11 months ago and it never worked.

[image]

`ping time.windows.com`

```
Pinging twc.trafficmanager.net [20.101.57.9] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 20.101.57.9: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=112
Reply from 20.101.57.9: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=112
Reply from 20.101.57.9: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=112
Reply from 20.101.57.9: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=112

Ping statistics for 20.101.57.9:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 47ms, Maximum = 50ms, Average = 47ms
```

Any ideas?

Tried different servers:

```
time.google.com
time.nist.gov
```

Still nothing, so it's the issue on Windows part

Tried

```
sfc /scannow
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Also nothing

Comment: try xx.pool.ntp.org ... where `xx` is **your** country code (no idea what country you're in)

Comment: @JaromandaX I 100% believe the issue is not about server, tried yours as well and others, still nothing. The issue is definitely on the Windows part

Comment: Are you behind any kind of firewall? Can you check in Wireshark whether Windows is _attempting_ to sync? Do you have non-Windows systems to test with? (Windows uses a specific NTP mode that sometimes gets blocked as a false positive for being an "NTP server".)

Comment: @u1686_grawity I have Windows Center enabled by default, no third-party firewalls.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I have tested with my phone internet (Cellular network) and shared wifi to pc and it worked, so it mb my router or internet home provider

Comment: @user25 It's either related to your router's firewall or router's DNS settings _(the latter can be ruled out by changing Windows WiFi adapter DNS to `1.1.1.2` and `1.0.0.2` - if NTP works, it's router's DNS settings, otherwise it's the router's firewall)_

Comment: @JW0914 I asked my internet home provider and they answered: "Most likely, this is due to the fact that when using a dynamic real IP address, port 123, which uses this protocol, is blocked. Unfortunately, it is often used to carry out network attacks. In such cases, we recommend using our synchronization server. Access to it is open." I tried their server and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked my internet home provider and they answered: "Most likely, this is due to the fact that when using a dynamic real IP address, port 123, which uses this protocol, is blocked. Unfortunately, it is often used to carry out network attacks. In such cases, we recommend using our synchronization server. Access to it is open."

I tried their server and it works fine :)